# merge facet label plot facetted by two columns with ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a facetted plot by two different columns in the data,`Type` and `UG`. I have moved one of the labels for the facets (`Type`'s label) to the outside to substitude the y-axis label, because I wanted different labels for the y-axis. Now I would like to move the labels for the other facet (`UG`'s labels) to the top of the plot.

```
ggplot(data = subset(Factors.longer, EQ == "CSI"), 
       aes(x = Girder, y = LLDF, fill = factor(S,levels = c("9","12","15")))) +
geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
                 fatten = 1, lwd = 0.2) + theme_classic() +
    stat_summary(fun = mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=0.5, stroke = 0.2,
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) + 
    stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', linetype=1, width=0.5, lwd = 0.2, 
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  geom_point(data = (subset(Factors.longer, Factor_EQ == "Factor 1 Proposed")), 
               aes(shape = Factor_EQ), stroke = 0.3, size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  geom_point(data = (subset(Factors.longer, Factor_EQ == "Factor 2 Proposed")), 
               aes(shape = Factor_EQ), stroke = 0.3, size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  geom_point(data = (subset(Factors.longer, Factor_EQ == "Factor 3 Proposed")), 
               aes(shape = Factor_EQ), stroke = 0.3, size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5, col='gray', lwd=0.2) +
  annotate("segment", x=-Inf, xend=Inf, y=-Inf, yend=-Inf, size = 0.35) +
  annotate("segment", x=-Inf, xend=Inf, y=Inf, yend=Inf, size = 0.35) +
  annotate("segment", x=-Inf, xend=-Inf, y=-Inf, yend=Inf, size = 0.35) +
  annotate("segment", x=Inf, xend=Inf, y=-Inf, yend=Inf, size = 0.35) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0,2,4), labels=c("Factor 1", "Factor 2", "Factor 3")) +
      labs(x = element_blank(), shape = element_blank(), 
           fill = "Analytical Data with \n Girder Spacing (ft) of:") +
    theme(legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.position = "bottom", 
          axis.text.y = element_text(size=8, colour="black"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, colour="black", vjust=0.6),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size=8, colour="black", vjust=0.5, margin = margin(0,4,0,-6)),
          axis.line=element_blank(), strip.placement = "outside",
          axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.2),
          legend.text = element_text(size=8, margin = margin(0,5,0,0)),
          legend.title = element_text(size=8, margin = margin(0,2,0,0)),
          strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          strip.background = element_blank(),
          legend.spacing.x = unit(0.1, 'cm'), legend.spacing.y = unit(0.1, 'cm'),
          legend.background = element_blank(), legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 0.2)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom", label.hjust = 0.8, title.vjust = 0.8,
                             override.aes = list(shape = c(23))),
         shape = guide_legend(keywidth = unit(3, "mm"),keyheight = unit(7, "mm"))) +
 facet_wrap(UG~Type, scales='free_y', strip.position = "left", dir = "h",
                labeller = as_labeller(c(Moment = "Moment LLDF", Shear = "Shear LLDF",
                                         `84` = "UG-84", `92` = "UG-92", `100` = "UG-100",
                                         `108` = "UG-108", `116` = "UG-116", `124` = "UG-124")))  +
     ylab(NULL)
```

[image]

Every coupled plots next two each other in the columns of each row share the same `UG-..` label. I would like to move the `UG-..` label to the top of the facetted plots and then if possible merge the common facets.

The desired output would look something like:

[image]

Some rows of the data:

```
> dput(Factors.longer[sample(seq(1,2808,1),50),])
structure(list(Factor = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Factor 1", 
"Factor 2", "Factor 3"), class = "factor"), UG = c(108, 116, 
100, 84, 116, 108, 116, 84, 116, 92, 84, 100, 100, 108, 116, 
92, 84, 84, 92, 100, 116, 124, 124, 108, 100, 108, 108, 116, 
84, 124, 100, 108, 108, 124, 124, 108, 92, 100, 124, 92, 84, 
84, 100, 84, 124, 100, 108, 124, 116, 116), S = c(9, 12, 9, 9, 
15, 12, 9, 12, 15, 9, 9, 12, 15, 9, 9, 12, 15, 9, 12, 12, 9, 
12, 15, 12, 9, 9, 15, 9, 9, 15, 9, 12, 12, 12, 15, 9, 9, 15, 
9, 12, 12, 9, 12, 9, 15, 12, 15, 12, 12, 9), X = c("Moment.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Moment.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", 
"Shear.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Moment.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Int.CSI", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", 
"Moment.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Moment.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Int.CSI", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", 
"Shear.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", 
"Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", 
"Moment.Int.Proposed"), LLDF = c(0.533626409014319, 0.866405751413225, 
0.55765289242222, 0.711779585132152, 0.755186097872227, 0.800521967280557, 
0.491782992127421, 0.97614497639116, 0.794494246323854, 0.721101826662558, 
0.489418420320527, 0.80692500307713, 1.1401304762799, 0.532652061886602, 
0.581471397249951, 0.812616128459131, 0.821315397629657, 0.711779585132152, 
0.71012956439832, 0.851654824223441, 0.619610859476547, 0.916394738328302, 
0.915158721599485, 0.8143070793053, 0.716044123419053, 0.491031387041157, 
1.1309453929435, 0.581471397249951, 0.556659207027632, 1.15049317588068, 
0.490595996384418, 0.97952581080398, 0.745402203471413, 0.639770642593863, 
0.943170217245197, 0.559436941693265, 0.581174226731532, 0.958941443941545, 
0.562484996706972, 0.682125285585693, 0.828741547701049, 0.621407677361543, 
0.841349803198735, 0.556659207027632, 1.09531764896839, 0.841349803198735, 
0.93862143013564, 0.721642237814207, 0.698798472866865, 0.491782992127421
), Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Moment", "Shear"
), class = "factor"), Girder = c("Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", 
"Exterior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", 
"Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", 
"Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", 
"Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", 
"Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", 
"Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", 
"Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", 
"Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Interior Girder", 
"Exterior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", 
"Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Interior Girder", 
"Interior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", 
"Interior Girder", "Exterior Girder", "Interior Girder", "Interior Girder"
), EQ = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CSI", "Proposed"), class = "factor"), 
Girder_S = c("Ext 9", "Int 12", "Ext 9", "Ext 9", "Int 15", 
"Ext 12", "Int 9", "Ext 12", "Int 15", "Ext 9", "Int 9", 
"Ext 12", "Ext 15", "Int 9", "Int 9", "Ext 12", "Int 15", 
"Ext 9", "Ext 12", "Int 12", "Int 9", "Ext 12", "Int 15", 
"Ext 12", "Ext 9", "Int 9", "Ext 15", "Int 9", "Int 9", "Ext 15", 
"Int 9", "Ext 12", "Int 12", "Int 12", "Ext 15", "Ext 9", 
"Ext 9", "Int 15", "Ext 9", "Int 12", "Int 12", "Int 9", 
"Int 12", "Int 9", "Ext 15", "Int 12", "Int 15", "Ext 12", 
"Int 12", "Int 9"), Factor_EQ = c("Factor 2 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", 
"Factor 3 Proposed", "Factor 2 Proposed", "Factor 3 Proposed", 
"Factor 2 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", 
"Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 3 Proposed", 
"Factor 2 Proposed", "Factor 2 Proposed", "Factor 2 Proposed", 
"Factor 2 CSI", "Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 2 Proposed", 
"Factor 2 Proposed", "Factor 3 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", 
"Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 3 Proposed", "Factor 3 Proposed", 
"Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 3 Proposed", 
"Factor 3 Proposed", "Factor 3 CSI", "Factor 2 Proposed", 
"Factor 2 Proposed", "Factor 3 Proposed", "Factor 2 Proposed", 
"Factor 3 Proposed", "Factor 2 Proposed", "Factor 2 Proposed", 
"Factor 3 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", 
"Factor 3 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", 
"Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 2 Proposed", "Factor 2 Proposed", 
"Factor 3 Proposed", "Factor 2 Proposed", "Factor 3 Proposed", 
"Factor 3 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed", "Factor 1 Proposed"
)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(UG = c(84, 
84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 
108, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 124, 124, 124, 124, 
124, 124, 124, 124), S = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 12, 12, 15, 9, 9, 12, 
12, 12, 9, 9, 9, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 9, 9, 9, 9, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 15, 15, 9, 9, 9, 9, 12, 12, 15, 15, 9, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 
15, 15), Factor = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Factor 1", "Factor 2", "Factor 3"
), class = "factor"), X = c("Shear.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", 
"Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", 
"Moment.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", 
"Moment.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", 
"Moment.Int.CSI", "Moment.Int.CSI", "Moment.Int.Proposed", "Shear.Int.Proposed", 
"Moment.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", 
"Moment.Int.Proposed", "Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Moment.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", "Shear.Ext.Proposed", 
"Shear.Int.Proposed"), .rows = list(42L, c(4L, 18L), c(29L, 44L
), 11L, 8L, 41L, 17L, 37L, 10L, 16L, 40L, 19L, 25L, 3L, 31L,
20L, 12L, c(43L, 46L), 38L, 13L, 1L, 14L, 36L, 26L, 24L, 
6L, 32L, 33L, 27L, 47L, c(7L, 50L), 21L, 15L, 28L, 49L, 2L, 
9L, 5L, 39L, 34L, 48L, 22L, 35L, 30L, 45L, 23L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-46L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = 
c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I don't believe there's a straightforward way to do merged facet headers without some hacking, either by manipulating the output afterward https://stackoverflow.com/a/40838827/6851825, or by constructing all the separate pieces you want and assembling them, potentially with the `patchwork` package.

Comment: @JonSpring, I am looking to keep one singular legend for the plots. Is there a way to do that with `patchwork`?

Comment: Yes: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html#controlling-guides